# Kotlin Show my list elements from bottom to top in lazy column

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

i have a kotlin list that i'm using in lazy column

`val list = ListOf(1, 2, 3, 4)`

```
@Composable
fun LazyMatchesRow(nums: List<Int>){

    LazyColumn() {

        items(items = nums) { numbers ->
            MatchesRow(nums = numbers)
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm getting the result in lazy column as:

1

2

3

4

now i want to display this list from bottom to top like

4

3

2

1

How can i do this?

I've tried using the function

```
nums.sortedByDescending {  }
```

but it is expecting something in the curly bracket.
i just want my list to start from the last element and end in first element

Comment: Have you tried using `nums.reversed()`?

Answer (score 4):

Although `nums.reversed()` works, but I think you should not change your data. Instead, change the way you display it by using `reverseLayout = true` in your `LazyColumn`.

```
@Composable
fun LazyMatchesRow(nums: List<Int>){

    LazyColumn(reverseLayout = true) {

        items(items = nums) { numbers ->
            MatchesRow(nums = numbers)
        }
    }
}
```